# The + button to create a new terminal in VS Code has disappeared. How can I add it back?

Tags: visual-studio-code

related with github bugreport: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182008

I used to have a '+' and split button here at the top right of the Integrated Terminal Panel of VS Code that I could use to add new terminals.

(like this):
[image]

Now the button and the dropdown menu next to it are no longer there.

[image]

How can I restore it?

P.S.:
I can't pass images in the comments under answers, so I'm passing them (images) here:
[image]
After clicking on the buttons from this menu, the ticks do not remain.
[image]

latest version + nothing changed
[image]

Comment: A non-googled duplicate means. Although the interface of vscode is also not intuitive

Comment: latest version + nothing changed with this button...

Comment: I'm really not sure what the issue could be anymore. what if you reset your view locations by running the `View: Reset View Locations` command in the command palette? Any change?

Comment: nothing has changed in the 3-dot button

I also Googled a lot - I don't understand where the button disappeared.

Comment: at this point, I'd suggest reporting a bug to the VS Code maintainers. Use the `Help: Report Issue ...` command. Please also [edit] your question post to add a link to your issue ticket once you've made it.

Comment: Done - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182008

Comment: Unfortunately, an inadequate moderator got caught there, I don't know what to do...

Comment: That "moderator" isn't inadequate. You just didn't respect their time. You should have seen that closure coming to be honest. You should have started by telling them everything you already tried in that post itself instead of linking to here, where even your description of everything you tried is not that great. Your issue sounds like something specific to your machine. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @user A good developer/moderator, if there is a lack of information or unwillingness to follow links, will simply say "please transfer everything from CO + here, tell us what you have tried". I've already done it

1 sentence.

Instead, I observe the most vicious practice when solving problems on github - when an administrator intervenes, despite a detailed description of the problem, he immediately close the task and remain silent.

Comment: @user Respecting the developer's time is important. But it is also important to respect the time of the user who was not too lazy and wrote a bug report. And closing the problem without coordination is the maximum disrespect.

Answer (score 0):

Right click any of the action buttons in the action button menu. In the context menu that pops up, find the item that says "New Terminal". It's probably unchecked, in which case, click it to give it the check mark again (make it visible).

For example, right click on the three-dot button or the trash button.

[image]

There's also the "Reset Menu" item, which resets the action menu to show everything it shows by default with a fresh installation of VS Code.

Comment: after clicking on new terminal, a new terminal appears. But the + button does not appear.

Comment: @Avraam can you edit your question post to show exactly what you're clicking on? Maybe I'm just not communicating clear enough and you're not clicking on what I mean for you to click.

Comment: done - see it in P.S. block of issue

Comment: After clicking on the buttons from this menu, the marks do not remain...

Comment: @Avraam 1) what do you mean by "the marks do not remain"? 2) what happens if you click "Reset Menu"?

Comment: On your screenshot there are ticks opposite the 3 points:
1) Focus terminal
2) Split terminal
3) Kill terminal
These ticks in my case are not put after the click (do not remain).

I don't have a "Reset Menu" button. three-dots button open only 4 items, see my 4rd screenshot.