# Not finding the terminal switching "+" option in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

`suddenly i dont see the terminal switching "+" option (cmd,powershell,bash) how to find the settings[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKsEN.png)

I tried many settings but didnt found the expected one,

.....................................

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal switching option"?  Are you asking how to create a second (or third) terminal tab?

Comment: yes and there was a option "+ v" option which is not showing now, you can see my ss given in the post

Comment: Does Ctrl-Shift-` (grave accent) work?

Comment: it is creating new terminal but all are powershell cant create different terminal

Comment: I don't understand how the '+' button could go away.  You might double-check your terminal profile as described here:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76213795/11107541 except I can't close vote because the answer there isn't accepted or upvoted :/